# Count items separated by commas from a list

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = spark.sql("""

SELECT list

FROM categories

""")

df.show()
```

| list |
| --- |
| 1,1,1,2,2,apple |
| apple,orange,1,2 |

How can I generate a field that counts the elements separated by commas? The ideal dataframe looks like this:

| list | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1,1,1,2,2,apple | 6 |
| apple,orange,1,2 | 4 |

I would also like to create looks like this:

| list | frequency_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| apple | 2 |
| orange | 1 |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is laborious to write using dataframe, and the SQL implementation is as follows.

```
count_df = df.withColumn('count', F.size(F.split('list', ',')))
count_df.show(truncate=False)

df.createOrReplaceTempView('tmp')
freq_sql = """
    select list,count(*) count from
        (select explode(flatten(collect_list(split(list, ',')))) list
        from tmp)
    group by list
"""
freq_df = spark.sql(freq_sql)
freq_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two questions. To get the count of items of a ',' separator string you can do like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=["1,1,1,2,2,apple", "apple,orange,1,2"], columns=["list"])
df["count"] = df["list"].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(",")))
print(df)
```

which gives as output:

```
                  list  count
0      1,1,1,2,2,apple      6
1     apple,orange,1,2      4
```

I use a lambda function here which does the operation *split* on each item (returning a list of separate items in the string) and then counts the items with *len()*. You can use the *apply* method to apply the lambda function to each item in the column.

In the second question you want to count the unique elements of each item in the dataframe. You can first use the *split* method to split the string items into separate columns:

```
df_items = df["list"].str.split(",", expand=True)
print(df_items)
```

which gives you a dataframe like this:

```
       0       1  2  3     4      5
0      1       1  1  2     2  apple
1  apple  orange  1  2  None   None
```

Then, since the location of each unique item does not matter you can glue all the columns together to one single column using the *melt* method. The *melt* method puts all the items in a column called *value*. You can get the item count of the columns using *value_count*. The script looks like this:

```
frequency_count = pd.melt(df_items)['value'].value_counts()
frequency_count.index.name = "list"
frequency_count = pd.DataFrame(frequency_count).rename(columns={"value":  "frequency_count"})
```

which gives you the output

```
        frequency_count
list                   
1                     4
2                     3
apple                 2
orange                1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['count'] = df['list'].map(lambda x: len(x.split(",")) if isinstance(x, str) else 0)
```

**Considering you have "list" column in dataframe, which is having comma separated values**
*Here I have combined lambda with if condition. If construct first check if each instance is of type string. If yes, then only it splits by comma and finds length. Else it return 0*